# A strange edit review

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

I have seen several strange edit review propositions:

[image]

What is being edited here? How can I know if the edition is correct? Why can't I improve? (the last one is merely technical question - I won't "improve" what I don't understand)

I have skipped two of such, but it is no good - I must know what to do with such reviews, too.

Comment: These are tag wiki edits.

Comment: See [`dropdownchecklist`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dropdownchecklist)

Comment: @devnull Oh, I see. Could you make it an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same surprise recently, as I just went over the 5K reputation mark too.

I just skipped my first one I had, but I don't know if clicking "reject" was the right choice on the second one I received, now that I think about it...

So if you're not sure, just skip it. Also, I think you can use the filter and not select tag wiki edits if you don't want to see those ones.

> Voting on tag wiki edits
>
> All registered users can submit edits for tag wikis. When approving
>   these edits, ensure that:
>
> ```
> All the content is original or attributed properly
> Wiki excerpts are concise and contain an objective description of the tag
> ```
>
> When you approve tag wiki edits the person submitting the edit will
>   gain 2 reputation points.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits

Comment: Thank you, I already know it from devnull, but as he doesn§t want the upvote and answer check, you get it :=) . I only don't understand why I have got 3 minuses for this post...

Comment: Yes. I mostly feel here myself as an curious elephant child from Kipling's story here. I could understand downvoting when I am asking for opinion - ok, it is voting. But when I am asking for help? I simply don't understand. Public different sites of stackexchange and even different themes is not the same at all. In Haskell or Python they get tens of votes for a simple answer similar to many on the page. In UML you have +1-2 for a true article. In Java you get minuses for Android thinking. And vice versa. And this is on the same tag! The most soft site, AFAIK, is Programmers.